# How to create an association between two entities that do not have an identical shared key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, associations

I have three entities in my model.

Loan,Limit and Customer entities as follows :

**Loan**:

```
LoanId => LD123456789 

CustomerId => 11223344

LimitId =>  5001.01
```

**Limit:**

```
LimitId => 11223344.5001.01
```

**Customer:**

```
CustomerId => 11223344
```

Knowing that LimitId in Limit entity is composed of (CustomerId + #some id#) but LimitId in Loan entity is only #some id#

Limit to Loan is 1-to-many

Customer to Loan is 1-to-many

So is it possible to create this association between Loan and Limit in EF6?

Comment: Wow, I thought `Composite Primary Keys` were for exactly this kind of problems...

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Why you removed the EF-6?! My question is not related to how to do in database.I can't change database schema and have to use the column Limit Id as it is ( its not a composite primary key - its one column )

Comment: I removed EF6 because your problem is not exactly related to it, the general EF tag is enough. Entity Framework probably cannot help you in this case

Comment: You can add virtual properties to your model class but I am not sure you can create Navigation properties from them. You may be better off with a View in your database.

Comment: There is no database constraint that will help you with this, database constraints rely on the equality of two values, so there can't be an association on DB side. If you have to keep this schema, you should create proper clustered indexes and do an index-"join" in memory, however I'd strongly suggest refactoring your schema so you can do joins and enforce FK constraints.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Can I define a new property manually in the class definition for the concerned table? Will it be overwritten when I click on "Update model from database"?

Comment: Yes you can, depending on your initializer a matching database might be created in this case. If you click on "Update model from database", the model in your code is overwritten with the model computed from the database.

Comment: So everytime I update model from database,I have to redefine my property.